# Bot doesn't go over switch case properly | Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am going over my discord bot trying to refactor my code a little and I have this switch case which works perfectly with if/else but it doesn't run in the switch. Any ideas why? I tried a lot of things but I can't get it to work... I am also pretty sure it is a dumb mistake I am doing..
The case in question is the "self" case that is not running.
So in normal circumstance it would be

```
if (getTag == self) {
   // code
}
```

Here is the code.
Thanks in advance!

```
var getTag = message.mentions.users.first(); 
var self = message.author.id;
switch (getTag) {
    case undefined: 
        // sample
        break;
    case self:
        // sample
        break;
    case client.user: 
        // sample 
        break;
    default: 
        // sample
        break;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the if-else code that is working currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.mentions.users.first()` returns a User object. It means, you can't simply compare it to other objects or strings.

Your first case, `undefined` will work, because `message.mentions.users.first()` returns undefined if there are no mentions.

The second one won't work, because you try to compare an object to a string (a user ID).

The third one won't work either as you're trying to compare a User object to another User object.

Try to only compare its `id` property or even better, get rid of the switch statement and use if statements instead:

```js
const getTag = message.mentions.users.first();
const self = message.author;

if (!getTag) {
  // same as case: undefined
  return;
}

if (getTag.id === self.id) {
  // same as case: self
  return;
}

if (getTag.id === client.user.id) {
// same as case: client.user
  return;
}

// same as default case
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I will go back to if statement. I just thought switch would look better but instead it rekt my whole bot :D

Comment: You're welcome, I also prefer if statements :)

Answer (score 0):

You compare an User Object with a User ID so you need to change the `getTag` to the following code:

```js
var getTag = message.mentions.users.first() ? message.mentions.users.first().id : undefined;
```

Comment: This will throw an error if there are no mentions.

Comment: I've changed my code, thanks @ZsoltMeszaros